# iOS 5: How can I create a UIAlertView with a UIPickerView? (iPhone / iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uipickerview, uialertview

I need a way of allowing a user to pick on option out of a list, I'm thinking of using a `UIPickerView` in a `UIAlertView`. However I was wondering if:

1. It's possible to put a `UIPickerView` in a `UIAlertView` easily in `iOS 5` (if so is it frowned upon by apple & will be app be rejected?)
2. Is there a better way of doing this? (if so, what?)

Any help or advice would be really appreciated!

Comment: Its possible, but I think it would look odd... Look into what people do to add text fields to UIAlertViews, See if you can do a similar thing with a picker view...

Comment: why not adding a UIPickerView and a UITextField on a separate page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are choosing a value to be put into a text field on the screen, just make your picker view the `inputView` of the text field. It will then animate into place for you just like the keyboard.

You may also wish to add a toolbar as an `inputAccessoryView` with done, next etc. buttons on it.

Making the picker view the input view is very simple. In your viewDidLoad method, create the picket view, setting its datasource and delegate as normal, then just assign it to the input view property of the text field:

```
myTextField.inputView = myPicker;
```

In your picker view delegate methods, you can update the text field with the selected value when the picker's selection is changed. In your text field delegate methods, you can make sure the picket has the right value selected before it appears (willBeginEditing? (guess, not at the mac ATM)).

The accessory view can just be a UIToolbar with a single done item that tells the text field to resign first responder status. Again, set this up and assign it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I really like the sound of this idea, please could you elaborate on how I can make the picker view the inputView?

Comment: I've added a bit more. On the mobile site so no sample code, sorry! If you hit any problems, give me a shout.

Comment: That was really really helpful. I've managed to get it working perfectly - Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible to add a `UIPickerView` as a subview of a `UIAlertView`, and I doubt Apple would reject your app because of it, but I think it would make for a poor UI. Why not just create a new `UIViewController` subclass to contain the `UIPickerView` and present it modally? That's a much more common interaction pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2-3 choices put several buttons into UIAlertView after otherButtonTitles:. If you have more choices, definitely you need to build new view controller. Don't even try to add picker view into UIAlertView.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can easily do this in any of the iOS SDK versions, I believe. Since `UIAlertViews` are basically subclassed `UIViews`, you can simply use `addSubview:`

2) This depends the context of the options list. For choices like birthdays or date or time, Apple uses a separate `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` (one row) and a `UIPickerView`. If it's none of the three above, Apple generally seems to use a `UITableView` which puts a checkmark next to the person's choice.

Either way, I think everyone seems to agree that you should bring up a second page with the list of options.